# Why is uniq ignoring Unicode and lines with a single letter?

Tags: text-processing, sort, locale, unicode, uniq

I'm trying to combine both the American and British dictionaries into one large dictionaries, and I'm trying to remove all the duplicates from the superset, but it seems that uniq is not outputting words like, "épée" or single letters.

This is what I've tried using:

```
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8 cat american-english british-english |sort|uniq -u > unique_sorted_combined_dict
```

If I just do this:

```
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8 cat american-english british-english |sort > sorted_combined_dict
```

"épée" and other such words do show up, along with single letters.

Is there something I'm missing here with `uniq`?

I should note that I'm using uniq from the GNU coreutils on Ubuntu 12.10, if that makes any difference.

Comment: What if you do 'LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8 cat american-english british-english |sort > temp && cat temp | uniq > sorted_combined_dict' ?

Comment: I decided, per your comment, to just take out the -u flag, and now it's working.  I don't know why -u is not giving me the expected results though.

Comment: @supercheetah I think I made the same mistake as you when it comes to `uniq`. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394205/45386 answered my concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting `LC_COLLATE` for the `cat` command only (which doesn't make use of it), while you need to set it for `sort` and `uniq`.

Also, you may need to set `LC_CTYPE` to something utf-8, otherwise it will cause confusion. I would set **`LC_ALL`** to `en_US.UTF-8`

`uniq -u` only reports **unique** lines. So, if those single letter words all appear several times, it's normal that they don't show up.

On my system, *épée* does appear twice:

```
$ cat american-english british-english | sort | grep -x 'épée'
épée
épée
```

Maybe you meant `sort | uniq` or `sort -u`.

Comment: Yeah, I obviously misunderstood what the `-u` flag does, and I think that was the cause of my problems. Thanks!