# Difference between using `sort -u` and `sort | uniq -u`

Tags: sort, uniq

I came into a level while exploring the bash that consisted of finding the line of text that occurs only once in a certain file.

Why is the output of the `sort -u file` command different from the output of `sort file| uniq -u`? Shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: The title and the body ask two different questions. `sort | uniq` **is** the same as `sort -u`, and `sort | uniq -u` is explicitly asking for a totally different behaviour; which one do you care about?

Comment: I edited to make the title and body consistent; revert if that isn't what you meant (otherwise, it's a duplicate of the question linked in the answer).

Comment: Yes, i misunderstood both commands. I initially thought that sort -u was the same thing as sort | uniq -u. Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`sort -u` and `sort | uniq` [do produce the same output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76049/what-is-the-difference-between-sort-u-and-sort-uniq?rq=1)*: all of the lines in the input, exactly once each, in ascending order. That is the default behaviour of `uniq`.

[`uniq -u`, on the other hand, asks to](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uniq.html):

> **`-u`** Suppress the writing of lines that are repeated in the input.

This is a very different behaviour: only the lines that *do not* repeat are outputted. When the file has been sorted first, that means the lines that only appear once in the entire file (which is what you wanted).

---

<sub>* There are some [caveats about how `sort` and `uniq` consider equality, which Stéphane has noted in this answer to a related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76095/73093). For the POSIX locale or files in some normalised form, they're identical; for others, there can be distinguishable differences.</sub>